# web page needed for bypassing proxy restricted sites

Tags: html

I am looking for ways to browse sites that are blocked by proxy filters at my location.

One solution i came up with was to build a page that would take a input of a URL and display the site in an iframe. Thus i would have a window into a browser on a page that is being displayed by my proxy. I was going to host this on my personal web site and use it to access restricted content. this way i have access to blogs, and forums where there is a wealth of information that is blocked by a backwards blanketed restriction list.

How can i make a web page similar to this? Would it be simple html and javascript, do I need .Net?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you aim to do has to be done server-side.  When you put a page in an iframe, your web browser loads it, and will do so just as if you went directly to the URL.

There is no way around this via client-side code, such as JavaScript.

If you truly want to reinvent the wheel, pick a language and look into whatever functions download files.  No need to do this though when there are plenty of web-based proxy services, such as http://www.hidemyass.com.

Comment: they are all blocked by my proxy as well.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you loaded it in an iframe, the request for the page in the iframe will still go through the proxy and so you will still be blocked.

You'd have to do something like open a socket to the site through your web host and then download the content and redisplay it. That's assuming your host isn't also blocked. Also, you'll lose the benefits of cookies and sessions this way (ie. you won't be able to be logged into things unless the session id is in the query string).

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and simplest solution would be to create a free Log Me In account at www.logmein.com. then setup your host computer at home, login from work, and browse freely. I do this myself at work so no one can see my personal browsing history when I dont want them to. This of course would only work if logmein.com was not a blocked site at your work. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the "filter" complexity. If you have your own website that you can reach through the proxy or if your computer can run as a webserver, you could try accessing via a proxy script such as "CGIProxy." There are online services that do this too. However, some proxy filters can detect these methods as well and you'd still be out of luck. No javascript or HTML tricks can overcome the proxy filter.